# I just want to know the difference of these two in vb.net? Using Data adapter and Using the oledb command?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledbexception

```
Private Sub Contestant_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim command As String
        Dim dsSET As New DataSet
        Dim connect As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\athan\Documents\PAGEANT.accdb")


        command = "SELECT * from Contestant "

        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command, connect)

        comSTR = "SELECT * from Contestant "

        dsSET.Clear()
        da.Fill(dsSET, "contest")





        dgvContestant.DataSource = dsSET
        dgvContestant.DataMember = "contest"


    End Sub
```

I don't understand the above code but it still fetches data from the database and load it to datagridview.

Below is another code but throwing  this error:
'Command text was not set for the command object.'

```
  Private Sub Contestant_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim dsSET As New DataSet
        Dim connect As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\athan\Documents\PAGEANT.accdb")
        Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand


        With cmd
            .Connection = connect
            .CommandText = "SELECT * from Contestant "
             Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command, connect)
            .Connection.Open()
            .ExecuteNonQuery()


            da.Fill(dsSET, "contest")
            dgvContestant.DataSource = "contest"
            .Connection.Close()
        End With




    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second code snippet, you're setting the `CommandText` of `cmd` but not setting the `CommandText` of `command`. It's `command` that that you then pass into the data adapter. Why do you have two command objects in the first place? If `cmd` is the command object whose `CommandText` you set then surely that should be the command object you pass into the data adapter.

A connection object creates a connection between your application and the database. SQL can be executed over that connection and data passed back and forth.

A command object contains SQL code and, optionally, the parameters for that SQL. A command is always associated with a connection over which it is executed. If the command contains a `SELECT` statement then you can call `ExecuteScalar` to retrieve a single value or `ExecuteReader` to retrieve zero, one or more records containing one or more columns. If the command does not contain a `SELECT` statement, you can call `ExecuteNonQuery`.

A data adapter is basically a group of up to four command objects to perform CRUD operations. When you call `Fill`, the `SelectCommand` is executed to retrieve data into a `DataTable`. When you call `Update`, the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` are executed as required to save changes from a `DataTable` to a database.

When you create a data adapter, you can either provide a ready-made command object for the `SelectCommand` or let the adapter create one itself. If you do the latter, you can pass the SQL code and an existing connection or you can pass the SQL code and a connection string, in which case the adapter will create the connection object too. A data adapter will not create its own `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` so you have to create those yourself or, in certain circumstances, you can use a command builder to do it for you.

You might benefit from a look at my ADO.NET examples [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases).

Comment: Thank you for the additional info. This is a bit quite an information overload for me. I want to clarify things based on my understanding of your reply.  I thought the .CommandText is already the Command since I declared cmd as OleDb.OleDbCommand. and cmd has the property .CommandText which you should put you SQL commands?? Please pardon my ignorance for this.

Comment: I have another question. You're giving me another insight into this. Since I can `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` using the data adapter. how can I use parameterized queries using a data adapter?

Comment: It appears that you haven't followed the link I provided yet.

Comment: Don't post wads of code in a comment. It's barely readable even formatted but certainly not unformatted. If this code clarifies your current question, edit and update your question. If this is a new question, post it as a new question and include all the information relevant to the new problem.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm already getting there. I'm still studying your codes from the link you gave me. I want to know if I need to declare a new data table even though I already have an existing database?

Comment: A DataTable is an in memory representation of a table in your database. It may contain only a portion of the records that are in your database table if it is filtered with a Where clause.

Answer (score 2):

A command is just a representation of a SQL statement and an associated connection. It can be executed in several ways, by returning a reader with `.ExecuteReader`, for Insert, Update and Delete statements with `.ExecuteNonQuery` and to retrieve a single value with `.ExecuteScalar`.

It can also be used by a `DataAdapter`.

A `DataAdapter` can not only `.Fill` a `DataTable` or `DataSet` but also `.Update`

Comments and explanations in line.

```
Private Sub Contestant_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Declares a variable as String
    Dim command As String
    'Creates a DataSet object. Note the New keyword
    Dim dsSET As New DataSet
    'Creates a Connection object and sets the .ConnectionString property by passing it to the Constructor of the object
    Dim connect As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\athan\Documents\PAGEANT.accdb")
    'Assigns a value to the previously declared String
    command = "SELECT * from Contestant "
    'Creates a DataAdapter object and provides a SQL Select statement that the adapter can use to create its SelectCommand property
    'and sets the .Connection property by passing a Connection object.
    'Note: the connection is NOT an open connection
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command, connect)
    'Undeclared and unnecessary variable
    'comSTR = "SELECT * from Contestant "
    'Unnecessary code - You just created, it is already empty
    'dsSET.Clear()
    'Calls the DatAdapter .Fill method passing the DataSet to fill and the name of the DataTable being filled.
    'The .Fill method opens and closes the connection if it finds it closed. If the connection is already open
    'the .Fill method leaves it open.
    da.Fill(dsSET, "contest")
    'The DataSet is set as DataSourd
    dgvContestant.DataSource = dsSET
    'Since a DataSet can contain more than one table; the .DataMember of the DataSet 
    'is set to the name of the DataTable to display.
    dgvContestant.DataMember = "contest"
End Sub

Private Sub Contestant_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dsSET As New DataSet
    Dim connect As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\athan\Documents\PAGEANT.accdb")
    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    With cmd
        .Connection = connect
        .CommandText = "SELECT * from Contestant "
        'Here command is not declared
        'Visual Studion assumes you mean Interaction.Command() which is NOT at all want you want
        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command, connect)
        .Connection.Open()
        'A DataAdapter does not have a .ExecuteNonQuery method
        '.ExecuteNonQuery belongs to .Command and is used for SQL statements that
        'begin with Insert, Update or Delete.
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
        da.Fill(dsSET, "contest")
        'The .DataSoure of a DataGridView cannot be set to a String
        dgvContestant.DataSource = "contest"
        .Connection.Close()
    End With
End Sub

'I don't think you need a DataAdapter or a DataSet

Private Sub FillDataGridView()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\athan\Documents\PAGEANT.accdb"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * from Contestant ", cn)
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    'Update the User Interface after the connection is closed.
    dgvContestant.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong my syntax  `da.Fill(dsSET, "contest")` I have `.fill` method and the string `"contest"` is the name of my data table? Am I correct?

Comment: In your first code snippet you have `da.Fill(dsSET, "contest")` That is 2 parameters. The first is a `DataSet` (`dsSet`) the second is a string (`"contest"`) which provides the name of the `DataTable`. The `DGV.DataSource` is set to the `DataSet` and the `DGV.DataMember` is set to the `String` `"contest"`. In the second snippet you try to set the `DGV.DataSource` to a `String` which won't work. Does this clear it up?

Comment: Thanks! I have another question. Based on your code snippet do I need to declare a `datable` every time I display data in dgv?

Comment: Yes, the first line of my code is the declare and initialization (New). It needs to be declared outside the Using block so it can be access after End Using when you update the User Interface.

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for the edit. Regarding the "a" or "an" before SQL, it depends on how you say it. If you say Sequel, then, yes, "a" is correct but I say SQL (pronounce the letters) where you ears should tell you that "an" is appropriate.